# boost spirit qi: change multiple target fields from semantic action

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I have the following input `123, test, test456` and I want to run a boost::qi grammar so that the output is a vector of pairs, where each match is associated with some kind of information like:
`[(123, Int), (test, String), (test456, String)]`

This is what I have been trying so far:

```
enum class MatchType
{
  Int,
  String
}
```

In the grammer

```
match = qi::alpha >> *(qi::alnum)[/*How to set the tuple to (matched value _1, string)*/]
       | +qi::digit[ /*How to set the tuple to (matched value _1, Int)*/ ]

/* Tied but doesn't compile:
         +qi::digit[ 
            []() 
            {
                phoenix::at_c<0>(_val) = _1;
                phoenix::at_c<1>(_val) = MatchType::Int;
            }]
*/


qi::rule<Iterator, std::vector<std::pair<MatchType, std::string>>> match;
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Sehe's answer is without a doubt the better approach(changing the order to what you need), but if you want to use semantic actions you just need to drop the lambdas: `qi::as_string[qi::alpha >> *(qi::alnum)][phx::at_c<0>(_val) = _1, phx::at_c<1>(_val) = MatchType::String] | qi::int_[phx::at_c<0>(_val) = _1, phx::at_c<1>(_val) = MatchType::Int]`. You'll need make sure you have either simply `#include <boost/phoenix/phoenix.hpp>` or at least `#include <boost/phoenix/statement/sequence.hpp>` (besides `<boost/phoenix/fusion/at.hpp>` obviously).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd simply suggest

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_pair.hpp>
```

and later

```
my_pair = (qi::attr(MatchType::Int)    >> qi::int_)
        | (qi::attr(MatchType::String) >> +qi::alnum);
```

Comment: Brilliant, that's exactly what is needed, simple and elegant